# Do I need to be employed to apply for German permanent residence after 21 months as a Blue Card owner?

Tags: germany, resident-permit, blue-card

21 months already has passed while I worked in Germany (Berlin) as Blue Card owner. Can I just quit the job, pass B1 exam and apply for permanent residence? Or is being employed at the time of application required?

Comment: How would you the show that you fulfill the condition of [§9 (2)(2) AufthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0128)? **2. the foreigner’s subsistence is secure,**

Comment: @MarkJohnson, may bank statement serve this role? If I show that I have enough savings for, say, 6 months.

Comment: Doubtful. Quiting you job after the minimal time needed and then asking for a permanent residence does not give a good impression.

Comment: @Mark Just to avoid confusion, he anyhow won't apply for the permanent residence permit according to §9 you have cited. However, your citation is still valid, since both §§ 9a and 18c have similar requirement or refer to §9 (2)(2).

Comment: @AndreySapegin In the case of BlueCard holders, both paragraphs reference §9 (2)(2) directly (§18c (2)). For others, §18c requires that they are still employed  in compliance with the requirements stipulated in sections 18a, 18b or 18d.

Comment: I don't know if it is formally required in this particular case but being employed is undoubtedly an asset when applying for permanent residence (or, incidentally, for citizenship) and having quit your job (as opposed to being laid off) potentially makes things worse. Is there a specific reason you want to quite your job now rather than after securing permanent residence? If you explain what you are trying to achieve, you may get better answers.